# Dual monitor support from one DVI port

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have just bought a HP Pavilion desktop with an AMD Radeon HD 7450 graphics card. This card has one DVI port and a HDMI port, and I want to hook it to up 2 monitors so I can use both as extended desktop (I don't just want to mirror the same output on 2 monitors).

According to the blurb [here](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14271_na/14271_na.HTML) it states `These cards support dual displays with its DisplayPort and dual link DVI connectors`. But there isn't a DisplayPort on the card! So, can I buy a splitter cable that will feed these 2 monitors, or am I better off buying a HDMI->VGA adapter for the HDMI port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, can I buy a splitter cable that will feed these 2 monitors, or am
>   I better off buying a HDMI->VGA adapter for the HDMI port?

You will need to purchase a HDMI to DVI cable.

This means you will need a monitor with a HDMI port or DVI port.

Comment: Thanks. All my monitors are VGA, is it possible to get a HDMI -> DVI adapter, and then plug that into a DVI -> VGA adator? Or is that not going to work because HDMI is digital, and VGA is analog?

Comment: @user41270 - This depends on the type of DVI connection on the cable.  Its very unlikely you will be able to find an HDMI to analog ( DVI ) cable.

Comment: Thanks, I think this might do the trick actually http://www.amazon.co.uk/Neewer-Black-Adapter-Converter-Laptop/dp/B007KEIRNG/ref=sr_1_2?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1354286760&sr=1-2

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted exactly?